# Is a South Korea visa needed for transit in Incheon?

Tags: visas, south-korea, vietnamese-citizens, us-residents

I'm a Vietnam passport holder and I live in The United States of America with Permanent Residence (green card holder). My trip will depart from Seattle, Washington for Seoul (going to stay in Seoul for 7 days) then to Vietnam (final destination).

Do I need to obtain a South Korea visa for this trip?

Answer (score 7):

No. From TIMATIC courtesy [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm):

> / 03NOV16 / 2018 UTC
>
> National Viet Nam (VN)          /Residence USA (US)
>   Embarkation USA (US)            /Transit Korea (Rep.) (KR)
>   Destination Viet Nam (VN)
>   ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>
> Korea (Rep.) (KR)
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a residence permit issued by USA to nationals of Viet Nam if:
>
> -holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within 30 days; when
>
> -arriving on a direct flight from USA, departing to a third country (e.g. USA-ICN-PVG); or
>   -arriving from a third country, departing to USA (e.g. PVG-ICN-USA).