# Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa for a layover in South Korea/Incheon?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, south-korea, icn

Below are the details

1. I am Indian citizen holding a valid visa to USA.
2. I am planning to travel from Delhi (DEL) to Los Angles (LAX) from Delta airlines via ICN (Incheon, South Korea)
3. I do **not** have any plan to leave airport during ICN layover.

**Please let me know if I need a transit visa for the layover.**

**Any Dos and Don'ts?**

Below is the proposed itinerary:

[image]

Comment: You're flying with Korean Air, by the way, not Delta. Keep that in mind when you look for check-in counters and such

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81954/is-a-south-korea-visa-needed-for-transit-in-incheon

Comment: @JonathanReez The question (duplicate of marked by you) is asked by Korean citizen. The transit visa or visa requirements are always specific to country of citizen. While Korean citizen may have different requirement, Indian citizen might have another requirements.

Comment: @GyanendraDwivedi the same answer as [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178174/as-a-chinese-national-can-i-layover-at-icn-airport-for-17-hours-before-next-ali?noredirect=1&lq=1) applies to you. Not sure which one you are referring to though, Korean citizens never need a visa to enter Korea.

Comment: @JonathanReez You have marked my question as duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81954/is-a-south-korea-visa-needed-for-transit-in-incheon

The transit visa need in any country is always specific to the citizenship of the traveler.
I am an Indian citizen, so my question is not duplicate to similar question asked by Korean/Chinese citizens. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

If you're transiting through South Korea on the way to the United States, you don't need a visa provided you stay within the sterile area of the airport and leave within 24 hours.

Per [South Korea's visa rules](https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=1010201) for tourists, before COVID you actually had the option to enter the country for up to 30 days if you were transiting to the U.S. and held a U.S. visa, but this has been and remains suspended.